# Access resource from inside jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I got a jar file test.jar that contains a folder resources which contains txtFile.txt.

I'm trying to access the file but the file seems to be null.

```
package main;

import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    private Test() {
        URL file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/txtFile.txt");
        System.out.println(file == null);
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you unzip the jar do you see the file?

Comment: Yes, The File is in the resource Folder inside the Jar

Comment: resource or resources? Your snippet says resources

Comment: Looks good then can you link the jar?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/yrvs73re4zcl46x/test.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getResource("resources/txtFile.txt");` (i.e. without the first `/`).

There should not be a leading slash when using the `ClassLoader`'s version of `getResource`, it will be interpreted as an absolute path always.

Comment: It's because when you use `Class.getResource` you use a '/' to indicate that the path is absolute, not relative to the class. It strips the leading '/' before delegating to the class loader.

Comment: @roby I see, thanks for the info. It is interesting that the very upvoted answer I originally linked to got this part wrong. I have removed that part from my answer and just provided the essence of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` are txtFile.txt is there in either of the two, you don't need `resources/` in path. You could use this insstead

`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/txtFile.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stream as File, you can request for InputStream using following:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/txtFile.txt"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the resource folder . You can directly user the file name as

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("txtFile.txt");
```

Comment: hmm. Can just give a try to put it in a package and call using the pckage name

Answer (score 0):

So i did this

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    private Test() {
        Class<?> c = this.getClass();
        ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
        InputStream[] iss = new InputStream[8];
        URL[] urls = new URL[8];
        iss[0] = c.getResourceAsStream("/resources/txtFile.txt");
        iss[1] = c.getResourceAsStream("resources/txtFile.txt");
        iss[2] = c.getResourceAsStream("/txtFile.txt");
        iss[3] = c.getResourceAsStream("txtFile.txt");
        iss[4] = cl.getResourceAsStream("/resources/txtFile.txt");
        iss[5] = cl.getResourceAsStream("resources/txtFile.txt");
        iss[6] = cl.getResourceAsStream("/txtFile.txt");
        iss[7] = cl.getResourceAsStream("txtFile.txt");
        urls[0] = c.getResource("/resources/txtFile.txt");
        urls[1] = c.getResource("resources/txtFile.txt");
        urls[2] = c.getResource("/txtFile.txt");
        urls[3] = c.getResource("txtFile.txt");
        urls[4] = cl.getResource("/resources/txtFile.txt");
        urls[5] = cl.getResource("resources/txtFile.txt");
        urls[6] = cl.getResource("/txtFile.txt");
        urls[7] = cl.getResource("txtFile.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            System.out.println("iss[" + i + "] is "
                    + String.valueOf(iss[i] == null));
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            System.out.println("url[" + i + "] is "
                    + String.valueOf(urls[i] == null));
        int read;
        try {
            while ((read = iss[0].read()) != -1)
                System.out.print((char) read);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Outprint:

```
iss[0] is false
iss[1] is true
iss[2] is true
iss[3] is true
iss[4] is true
iss[5] is false
iss[6] is true
iss[7] is true
url[0] is false
url[1] is true
url[2] is true
url[3] is true
url[4] is true
url[5] is false
url[6] is true
url[7] is true
This is sample text.
```

Conclusion: It worked when I used `getClass().getResource("/resources/txtFile.txt")` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/txtFile.txt")` ( `getResourceAsStream()` also works).